# Generate single report for multiple user using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I need to create student certificate using SSRS. I created new .rdl file did designed and associated with data source.

It works for single student as expected. But it does not creates report with multiple certificate while my data source returns multiple student details.

I am new for SSRS, please help me out to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to generate a certificate for each row of your dataset in the same report, you can do this with a `tablix`:

- Add a `Tablix` to you your report that lists your dataset data
- Drag a `Rectangle` into one of the `Details` row cells
- Make the cell you dragged the `Rectangle` into large enough to hold all your
- certificate report items
- Select all your certificate items and move them into the `Rectangle`
- Update any references to your dataset to not include a 'scope'

  - ie: Change `=sum(Fields!ColName.Value, "Your Dataset")` to `=sum(Fields!ColName.Value)`
- Run the report

You should now have a certificate for each row in your dataset.

If you want to export multiple separate certificates, you will need to set up a [data driven subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/create-a-data-driven-subscription-ssrs-tutorial) on your report, that runs it once for each row of a returned dataset.  Obviously you will need to adjust your report to be able to receive which student to generate the certificate for as a parameter.

Comment: Thank you! this solution worked for me. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is.. if your data set is returning one row per student, then all you need to do you on your tablix is to add a parent row group.. group on StudentID.. or something unique per record.. go to group properties and add a page break at end of group. This should generate one certificate page per student.. 
You may need to adjust group headings and footer and things like that appear.. You will figure it out... alternatively.. watch a youtube video on how to do a basic ssrs report.

Answer (score 0):

I have a subreport call StudentSub.rdl. This is linked with DataSet (stored procedure) Sp_GetStudentName(@ClassNo int). This works fine it gives always only one certificate.

Since I wanted to generate class wise certifiacte, in that case I wanted to get muliple report page wise in one PDF file. Followed below steps:

1. Created new RDL file called StudentReports.rdl
2. Linked with same data set stored procedure Sp_GetStudentName.
3. Drag a table from tool box to design body.
4. Set visibility False for table Header and some columns except one td.
5. Right clicked in that box (td) and inserted sub report
6. Right clicked sub report properties selected StudentSub subreport.
7. In the sub report properties added parameter ClassNo then clicked Ok.

Now When I am previewing this StudentReports by passing class no. I am getting correct number of pages.
Hope this will help others.
Thanks!